# How do you harvest Phase Lemons?

Tags: slime-rancher

I've found Phase Lemon trees in the Ruins area, but they look see-through and I can't seem to interact with them in any way. How can I obtain these fruits?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After finding a tree with ripe lemons on it, just shoot any other kind of fruit at it. This will cause the fruit to disappear and a Phase Lemon to drop from the tree.

Comment: Ripe is a keyword. No use if they are not ripe and it's not easy to tell if they are ripe just by the looks of it

Comment: @AndrewSavinykh Unripe lemons are much smaller than ripe ones.